# C# - Ntier App using EntityF - how to manipulate a POCO in UI layer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I am writing a Ntier app POC using EntityFramework.

I have 3 layers :

- the DAL, that contains the POCOs and the database model
- the Repositories that has reference to the DAL in order to allow getting and saving data
- the UI (graphic interface) (which is a Winform) that has reference to the Repositories to use data for display or allow user to modify data

Let's say the user wants to see an image of a car, present in my database.
UI is calling a method from my repository :

```
public Car GetCarById(int id)
{
    Car tmp = _db.Car.Where(a => a.idCar == id).FirstOrDefault<Car>();

    return tmp;
}
```

Now in my UI, I must get Car.Image which is Bitmap and set in to a pictureBox element so it is displayed.

Problem is : my UI layer doesn't have any reference to my DAL, so it doesn't know the object Car. It can not use that object and get the image in it, or any other property.

Question is : how can I manipulate the car object in my UI, other then adding a reference to DAL ?

This architecture is very commun, there must be a way to do it properly. Dont hesitate to tell me I didn't get the real role of each layer correctly. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why do you think adding a reference to the DAL is a problem? It's hard to work with objects without knowing what those objects are.

Comment: You could separate DAL and POCO (Models), reference Models in UI and even create ViewModels in UI and use automapper to map to exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre POCO classes does not have to be in your DAL layer.

1.UI layer  with Viewmodels.

2.ServiceLayer

3.RepositoryLayer --> actualy this is overhead because entity framework is a repository.

4.DataAccesLayer

5.SharedLayer --> this layer has reference's for al the other layers.
Here I put in my POCO's, extensionmethods, enums,....

This is how I set up the most common projects. U can even split those layers.
But do not create to much layers.

If u google on N-tier application using entity framework, you will find lots of different styles.
Just be aware of the frequent Unit of work / repository patern. because this is a big overhead for entity framework.

Comment: Thank you for that answer I will probably go for the SharedLayer. But I disagree with your opinion EF isn't quite a repository layer. I read a interesting blog this morning on that topic : http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2012/04/15/The-Repository-Pattern-Vs-ORM.aspx

Comment: http://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-part-2/

Check this article

Answer (score 1):

Your DAL or Data Access Layer is normally use to communicate with the persistence layer (in other words, the database). You'll implement the functions to Retrieve, Insert or Update data into your database.

Repository is a sort of DAL because his main goal is also to access the persistence layer but in a different way, using the [Repository pattern](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3107186/application-development/how-to-implement-the-repository-design-pattern-in-c.html). 
With the repository pattern you'll split the code that access and modify each entity from your database (table) in different classes (One by entity).
The repository pattern is commonly used with entity framework.

You'll have to choose between one of these two. 
I recommend to use the Repository Pattern with Entity Framework. There is a lot of doc for you online.

About passing objects between layers, [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493389/Four-ways-of-passing-data-between-layers#ProblemsandbenefitswithDTO) you have a good article explaining differents ways of implementing that but the main purpose is to have a Fourth layer who will be referenced in all the others layers. That layer will have all the POCOs that will be passed between the layers. 
I usually call this layer the Common layer.

Concerning the NTier architecture, you normally have four layers.

1. **UI layer** (Winform)
2. **Business Layer** (Here you put all the code that your business needs)
3. **DAL** or **Repository** (Here is the code that access to your database)
4. **The Common layer** (Referenced by all the others layers and containing the pocos and classes used throughout the application layers)

**The referencing schema** :

**UI** -> **BL** -> **DAL** or **Repository**
and **Common layer** is referenced by all the others

[image: Ntier architecture without the Common layer]

I explained it in a simplify way but you have the main idea behind the concept of Ntier architecture.
I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The UI must have access to the types it displays.  So if the types are defined in the DAL, the UI must reference the DAL.

However, you might be better defining the types in a separate project (called `Model`, for example), which is referenced by all the layers.